Variable selection strategies
I'm wanting to learn more about current best-practice approaches to variable selection, in the context of the reason for creating the model. I don't have much experience with modern methods like lasso, bootstrapping to calculate variable inclusion frequencies, etc and have been guilty of using stepwise selection methods - mainly in a predictive context, but want to change this. I am getting the general feeling from reading around that all of the problems that arise from data-driven variable selection (biased coefficients, small SE's/p-values, etc) occur because one is testing many different models. If a model was pre-specfied and not changed after its evaluation, these wouldn't be issues?
If models can be broadly classified as:

Explanatory/causal - variable selection should be driven solely by background knowledge/theory and ideally be supported with directed acyclic graphs. The model is pre-specified and not changed. You want to be able to interpret the 'effects' of the resultant coefficients.

Predictive - here you can select one from many potential models as you only really care about predictive performance and not so much about individual coefficients. Typically, a model is not pre-specified for this reason. So, something like the lasso would be ok as it provides some variable selections elements as well as optimising predictive performance (but my understanding is that you can't readily interpret lasso coefficients).

Descriptive - contain elements of both 1. and 2. - you are interested in prediction but also in interpretation of coefficient 'effects'. Here you can also select one of many potential models. I'm interested to know what is a good general guide for approaching variable selection in this context? The closest solution I have come to is to calculate bootstrap inclusion frequencies and select those most frequently appearing (to some threshold) variables. Or does this also not negate the problem?


Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Where did you hear that you can't " readily interpret lasso coefficients."? Why wouldn't you be able to?

I thought I read they were scaled or not in the original units at least...

I have never heard that.  The coefficients are penalized by making them closer to 0, but that, AFAIK, doesn't change the units.

Apologies - it seems for glm.net in R at least the variables are first standardised for the estimation and then (I think) are returned in their original units. I must have read something wrong. I assume that then means they can be interpreted as one normally does.

That's a very interesting question. In my area (computational biology) this is exactly what we are looking for since in all our problems we have a much greater number of variables than individuals. This is a major issue for the estimation of parameters from standard models. I will try a short but comprehensive answer to your question, focusing on the intuition rather the technical aspects.
Independently to the research objective, prediction or inference, feature selection is an elegant way to limit the number of variables. For a prediction task this is directly related to the Occam's razor principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). You are looking for a trade-off between the number of features and the predictive accuracy, limiting overfitting while improving result interpretability. For inference, you want only the subset of "significant" variables. As you correctly pointed you can easily mix these two objectives together.
Now, let's talk about the state-of-art about this topic, starting with the different models, I will present strategies to address some of the limits observed in current frameworks later. I am firstly focusing on frequentist models while Bayesian alternatives will be presented after.

Ridge: is probably one of the most well-known models to induce shrinkage on model coefficients. In a frequentist way Ridge can induce shrinkage but coefficients cannot be set exactly to zero. The shrinkage is obtained by imposing a L2 penalty on parameters. Posthoc strategies have to be implemented for removing unsignificant variables.
LASSO: Unlike Ridge, LASSO by L1 regularizing coefficients is able to shrink parameters to exactly zero, promoting sparsity and improving model interpretability. This is an automatic data-driven procedure for feature selection. However, LASSO lacks of the oracle property while performing bad in the presence of highly correlated features. Adaptive LASSO is a two-steps procedures addressing some of the limitations of the original LASSO.
Elastic-net: Is the fine combination of both Ridge and LASSO imposing a double penalty (L1 and L2) on model parameters. This model addresses the limitations mentioned above.
Group LASSO is a direct extension of LASSO permitting a global-local penalty when some structure is expected in the data (gene networks for example)

All these models estimate penalty parameters using Cross-Validation (CV), where some result variabilities have been observed due to the sampling variability, pushing researchers to adopt additional strategies (See below). Also, data standardization can be performed for model stability but is not mandatory if interpretation is required.
Before presenting complementary strategies, I would take few minutes to present Bayesian feature selection approaches, which are pretty interesting with appealing features for both inference or prediction.
Practically all feature selection models have a Bayesian correspondence. The only difference is how to induce shrinkage. Frequentist models estimate the penalty parameters using CV while sparsity is imposed through different choice of hierarchical priors in a Bayesian model. Briefly we have:

Bayesian Ridge: the model parameters are assumed to follow a Normal distribution.
Bayesian LASSO: the model parameters are assumed to follow a Laplace distribution.
Horseshoe: the model parameters are assumed to follow a Half Cauchy distribution. This is the go-to in most bayesian tools (PyMC, Stan etc...).
Spike-and-slab: the model parameters are assumed to follow a Mixture of gaussians. However, the posterior is hard to sample from due to the nature of the prior. Although this is considering as a gold-standard in the literature, many Bayesian tools explicitly recommend to instead use the Horseshoe.

One advantage of the Bayesian models over frequentist is to offer the set of Bayesian inference tools directly from the posterior. Indeed, formal inferences from frequentist feature selection models are very tricky. However, most of the Bayesian methods cannot set coefficients to exactly zero since continuous priors are assumed and posthoc strategies have to be implemented to remove some variables.
Finally let me conclude on the complementary strategies for addressing some of the limitations observed in frequentist feature selection methods. As already discussed, methods are based on CV. Since different CVs may lead to different set of kept variables, some authors have proposed to use Stability selection. The idea is pretty simple, you perform several CVs and you decide to keep only the variables which were kept in x% of the samples. In practice 80% or 90% are common thresholds. I refer readers on the original paper which is basically a blockbuster in modern statistics (https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2932).
From a slightly different perspective, Emmanuel Candès have proposed the Knockoff framework (https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02351). The idea is to create artificial new exchangeable variables mimicking the original data. If you original variable is associated with the outcome and its related knockoff variable too, so you can say that your original features is a true positive. A false positive in the opposite case. Knockoff has interesting properties in finite sample sizes with accurate controls of the False Discovery rate (FDR). You can easily combine both Stability selection and Knockoff to reach sparse powerful models (See https://www.nature.com/articles/s41587-023-02033-x).
As for many statistical models, your choice will depend on your goals. But ultimately no model is perfect.
If you want I elaborate more on a specific aspect, please let me know.
EDIT
Regarding R packages implementing the different models I have presented:

glmnet: for LASSO, Ridge and Elastic-Net
grplasso: for the group LASSO
knockoff: for generating knockoff data
stabsel: for stability selection

However, depending on your problem you will maybe push to implement your own solutions.

Thanks for your answer. Could you suggest R packages that accommodate penalisation (I presume glmnet is the main one) and stability selection - either with bootstrap or CV (and survival as well as glm's)? Or do you code this up manually each time you need to do it?

Hi @LucaS, I have provided a list of available R packages implementing the different approaches.
